# How to activate alias through python?

Tags: python, bash, flask, scrapy

I have python2( as default environment) and python3 installed on redhat server and set up different alias for them.

`.bashrc`

```
alias myconda='export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"'
```

I activate this alias by executing `myconda` on terminal. How can I activate it using python script as I need to run `scrapy` spider on python3?

**Update:** I want to integrate scrapy spider with flask as API. When `POST` method hit the endpoint url, then I want to run the scrapy spider. Currently spider runs fine individually.

I am trying to activate bash alias like this -

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('myconda;scrapy crawl company_pro;', shell=True)
```

This doesn't identify `myconda` as alias and uses default python2 environment instead of python3 to start spider and gives python2 syntax errors and

`/bin/sh: myconda: command not found`. error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a common FAQ. The absolutely simplest and most preferred solution is to not use an alias for this in the first place (or, more generally, at all).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstanding your requirement, how about use following:

```
python -m scrapy startproject xxx
```

You can choose your python still by environment or just use full path?

Comment: This does not solve my issue. I solved using `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'myconda;scrapy crawl company_pro;'])`. The `-i` flag is for interactive mode for bash.